# Bitbucket API to get the latest tag on a particular branch

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-tag, bitbucket-api, bitbucket-cloud

I want to get the latest tag on a particular branch.

For example, for a branch `release/fix`,  there are `n` commits, but for each commit, tags are not generated:

```
commit #111 - no tag present
commit #110 - tag 1.1.1
commit #109 - tag 1.1.0
commit #108 - no tag present
```

So, the latest tag would be `1.1.1` for the branch `release/fix`.

I need to get this via the Bitbucket API.

I tried to get the latest commit on a particular branch using `https://bitbucket.x.com/rest/api/latest/projects/{}/repos/myrepo/commits?until=refs/heads/release/fix&limit=1` and get the tags using `https://bitbucket.x.com/rest/tags/latest/projects/{}/repos/myrepo/tags` - POST call with the commit #.

But the issue with above approach is that it is not neccessary that the latest commit on that branch would have a tag associated with it.